# nodejs http.createServer read url and remove urlprefix

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

Here is what i want:

> I have an url "10.0.0.1/0000000/abctest/filedirectory/filename",
>
> and with this url, I can read the file accordingly

Thus, i create a server with "http.createServer" and binded at 8001 port, and set nginx that whenever it read /0000000/abctest/, it will redirect to port 8001

After i added the nginx reverse proxy, I try to write my server code, and here is my http server code

```
var port = 8001;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var DefaultFileDir = '/home/ubuntu/Server/Proj/static'; 
var UrlPrefix = "/0000000/abctest"
var hostname = "127.0.0.1"

//var host = hostname+UrlPrefix
var server= http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var url = req.url; 
    console.log(url);
    var file = DefaultFileDir + url;

    fs.readFile(file, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHeader(404,{
                'content-type' : 'text/html;charset="utf-8"'
            });
            res.write('<h1>404</h1>');
            res.end();
        }else{
            if(url.substr(url.length-3, 3) == ".gz"){
                res.writeHeader(200,{
                    'Content-Encoding' : 'gzip',
                    'content-type' : 'application/octet-stream'
                });
            }else{
                res.writeHeader(200,{
                    'content-type' : 'text/html;charset="utf-8"'
                });
            }
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });

}).listen(port,hostname);
console.log("Static file server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

And the problem come out:
it dont know how to ignore the url prefix "/0000000/abctest"

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/xxxxx/static/0000000/abctest/folder001/index.html'
```

However my actual file path shall be '/home/ubuntu/xxxxx/static/folder001/index.html'

is that http.createserver cannot ignore the url prefix? May i seek for some hints from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

I finally bypass the problem by rewriting the url with the use of nginx reverse proxy